# Scene Reconstruction with ARGeoTrackingConfiguration

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, arkit, realitykit

Is there a way to add Scene Reconstruction using ARGeoTrackingConfiguration in Xcode?

It appears it is only available for ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment it's impossible and it's easy to explain why. Scene Reconstruction feature is a computationally-intensive task (due to processing of LiDAR data, number of stored polygons, tracked anchors and classifications). And I am not counting the fact that you need simultaneous plane detection, raycasting, rendering of PBR shaders, shadows and physics at 60 fps.

But Geo Tracking is a highly expensive task too. Your gadget must process URLSession data, ML data, IMU data and GPS data in real time. I suppose we need a considerably powerful iOS device with a capacious battery for running Scene Reconstruction during Geo Tracking.

Comment: thanks! yeah I figured it had something to do with that - plus geotracking being an outdoor capability (so far) probably can cause all kinds of computational issues.  It would be nice to have occlusion with persistent objects though!